# MLR MARS/Earth classifier: flexible discriminant analysis or logistic regression?

Tags: r, mlr

I'm trying to learn about MARS/Earth models for classification and am using "classif.earth" in the MLR package in R.  My issue is that the MLR documentation says that "classif.earth" performs flexible discriminant analysis using the earth algorithm.

However, when I look at the code: 
(https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/master/R/RLearner_classif_earth.R)
I don't see a call to fda in the mda package, rather it directs earth to fit a glm with a default logit link.

So tell me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that "classif.earth" is not doing flexible discriminant analysis but rather fitting a logistic regression on the earth model.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation uses MARS to perform the FDA, where the MARS model determines the different groups. You can find more information in [this paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/fda.pdf); I quote from the abstract:

> Linear discriminant analysis is equivalent to multiresponse linear regression [...] to represent the groups.